# Store the all the neighbors of the vertexes, find a vertex's neighbors quickly

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Suppose I have `N` vertexes labeled from `0` to `N-1`. Each vertex has at most `3` neighbors and at least `1` neighbor. Suppose the neighbor information is initially stored at a vector called `pairs`, where `pairs[2*i]` and `pairs[2*i+1]` are a pair of neighboring vertexes.

**Now I need to look up very fast what the neighbors are for `vertex[i]`**, what's the best way to store this information?

---

The method I came up with is:

- declare a vector called `neighbors[3*N]`, so that `neighbors[3*i+0]` `neighbors[3*i+1]` and `neighbors[3*i+2]` stores three **possible** neighbors.
- why saying possible, because there are at most three neighbors for each vertex.
- so I initialize all the elements of vector `neighbors` to `N`, which means this is not a valid neighbor, since the vertexes are labeled from `0` to `N-1`.

The code implementation is as follows:

```
void get_neighbors(const std::vector<int>& pairs, 
        std::vector<int>& neighbors)   {
    int N = neighbors.size()/3;
    int M = pairs.size()/2;
    //init all the vertexes' neighbours to nothing
    for (int i=0; i<3*N; ++i)   {
        neighbors[i] = N;
    }

    //loop through all the vertexes, and store their neighbors
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)  {
        int j = 0;
        //loop through pairs, and find out what neighbors vertex[i] has
        for (int k=0; k < M; ++k) {
            if(pairs[2*k]==i)    {
                neighbors[3*i+j]=pairs[2*k+1];
                ++j;
            }
            else if(pairs[2*k+1]==i)    {
                neighbors[3*i+j]=pairs[2*k];
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things I feel uncomfortable with my method:

1. declare a vector `neighbors(3*N)` is too much, since many of its elements will be useless `N`.
2. If I want to look up `vertex[i]`'s neighbors, every time I need to test if `neighbors[3*i]==N`, `neighbors[3*i+1]==N` and `neighbors[3*i+2]==N`.

Comment: Use `vector<vector<int> > graph (N);` for every edge from `a` to `b` i.e. `b` is a neighbour of `a` and vice versa use : `graph[a].push_back (b);` This will declare a vector of `N` elements. **To get the neighbours since there are only 3 will take always constant time.**

Comment: @PRP Do you have time to write this as an answer and give some reference about `graph`? I am not familiar with the symbol `> graph(N)`? Your method seems clean enough, but what will the look up time compared with my method?

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>` will have even more overhead than the single vector `neighbours`; if 3*N elements is too much overhead then N `vector<int>`s are surely too much overhead as it will be even more overhead.

Comment: @buzhidao I have analysed 4 scenarios in my answer. Please take whichever one you find the best. **According to me the array of structs solution is the best and I have explained the reason also.**

Comment: @PRP Thanks for the detailed answer, I will have a good check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure that you are working with is a [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). But Graph is a more general concept in which a node can have any number of neighbours.

Since your problem is a more strict one saying each node has at-most 3 neighbours. **The solution I suggested in the comments is a general one that can be used for all the graphs and will work decently well for your case also.**

Declare a graph :

```
vector<vector<int> > graph (N);
```

If there is an edge from `a` to `b` the do this :

```
graph[a].push_back (b);
```

To retrieve the neighbours of a node `a` :

```
for (int i=0;i<graph[a].size();i++)
    // Do whatever you want with the neighbour. The variable graph[a][i] holds the neighbour number
```

Now coming to your problem of at-most 3 neighbours. **The best solution according to me is :**

```
struct node
{
    int data; // Some data related to the node. This is optional.
    int neigh_1;
    int neigh_2;
    int neigh_3;
}
```

And make graph as an array of nodes :

```
node[N] graph;
```

This will also take **3*N** memory. But this is a better approach that what you have done. Let me explain :

When you say give me the neighbours of node `x` :

Your method will access memory locations **x, 3*x, 3*x + 4, 3*x + 8**.

My method will access the memory locations **x, x+4, x+8, x+16**

Wait ! Why are we accessing `x` when we want only its neighbours ? It is a valid question, but if you need to process some value at node or store some information local to a node then we have to access `x`.

**Note : The approach I am suggesting will not perform worse than your approach. But it surely will perform better for a general case.**

**Why my approach is better ?**

My method will will result in lesser [cache misses](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/6308/cache-miss), because I am having a better spatial [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

If you don't care about the working of cache, in simple words my method will be accessing the locations that are closer to each other and hence have a very very high chance of already being in the faster memory cache which will lead to faster access.

Also someone might argue that **we should declare memory for a neighbour only when we require it.** Essentially the `vector` solution does that. But it will not perform well in this case because even declaring a pointer takes 8 bytes. But with that space you can store information of 2 integers, i.e. information about 2 neighbours.

**So dynamically allocating memory will not save any space as the maximum neighbours are 3.**

Comment: `for (auto ele : graph[a])`, sorry, I've never seen this code, is it a `for` loop? you seems to say that this get the number of neighboring elements of node `a`. Therefore if I want to use the neighbors, should I for example using `graph[a][i]` where `0<=i<ele`?

Comment: @buzhidao C++11/14 range based loop

Comment: @buzhidao I have changed the loop from C++11/14 style to the normal loop. Please check. Accept  and upvote the answer if you found it useful

Comment: I think you got wrong with my method, my method to use the neighbors of node `x` will just visit `3*x+0`, `3*x+1`, `3*x+2`, which are adjacent three. No need to visit `x`, since `x` only denote the vertex number.

Comment: @buzhidao  Yes. That is correct. See that The node has a field called `data` also. In general scenarios, you might want to do something with the data also, or store LCA, weight or something. Then the approach I proposed will be better. I am talking about a general scenario.

Comment: @PRP You are right, node will have some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a struct which contains the node value and indexes of the neighbours like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct vertex{
    int data;
    std::vector<int> neighbours;
};
```

A sample program that adds 2 neighbours to each of the nodes is given below. Each node has a value of its index squared.

```
int main(){
    vertex v[5];

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        v[i].data = i*i;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        v[i].neighbours.push_back((i+1) % 5);
        v[i].neighbours.push_back((i+2) % 5);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
         std::cout << "vector " << i << " has value " << v[i].data << std::endl;
        for (int j=0;j<v[i].neighbours.size();j++){
            int nodeNum = v[i].neighbours[j];
            std::cout << "vector " << i << " has neighbours " << v[i].neighbours[j] << " with data " << v[nodeNum].data << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will output you following

```
vector 0 has value 0
vector 0 has neighbours 1 with data 1
vector 0 has neighbours 2 with data 4

vector 1 has value 1
vector 1 has neighbours 2 with data 4
vector 1 has neighbours 3 with data 9

vector 2 has value 4
vector 2 has neighbours 3 with data 9
vector 2 has neighbours 4 with data 16

vector 3 has value 9
vector 3 has neighbours 4 with data 16
vector 3 has neighbours 0 with data 0

vector 4 has value 16
vector 4 has neighbours 0 with data 0
vector 4 has neighbours 1 with data 1
```

Since we have used vector for the neighbours. We can allocate any number of neighbours to our node. Which is a general case. And also is applicable to your requirement. Hope this helps

Comment: This is a nice treatment!

Comment: Thank you . Hope it helps  :)

Comment: This is just what I am looking for, my main concern is that my method has too many useless values...